# See if a user is following me from tweet JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

I'm using the twitter streaming API to catch tweets that contain a certain phrase. In the tweet JSON, is there a way to see if a user is following me (ie if the tweet author is following the authenticated user which initiated the stream)?

I noticed that tweets have a ***tweetObject.user.following*** property, but when that's ***true***, it seems to be because I am following the tweet's author, not the other way around.

Is there a way to accurately see if the tweet's author is following me, rather than do a request for my followers list and compare against that for every new tweet?

Thanks if anyone can give some info!

Answer (score 1):

Twitter REST API has a method to show user relationship data. See the documentation on https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friendships/show. It says:

> Returns detailed information about the relationship between two
>   arbitrary users.

The response contains `following` and `followed_by` fields in `source` and `target` user. This is the result sample:

```
{
"relationship": {
  "target": {
    "id_str": "12148",
    "id": 12148,
    "screen_name": "ernie",
    "following": false,
    "followed_by": false
  },
  "source": {
    "can_dm": false,
    "blocking": null,
    "muting": null,
    "id_str": "8649302",
    "all_replies": null,
    "want_retweets": null,
    "id": 8649302,
    "marked_spam": null,
    "screen_name": "bert",
    "following": false,
    "followed_by": false,
    "notifications_enabled": null
  }
}
}
```

I don't know if this can help you when using streaming API. But at least, you don't have to "*do a request for my followers list and compare against that for every new tweet*" like you've said above.

Comment: That's useful thanks, I'll probably go with this but was hoping there would be a way to have the data on the initial tweet to avoid an additional request - I'm watching those rate-limits...